# How to reinstall Docker after upgrade failure?

Tags: docker

I upgraded my Docker Desktop for Windows earlier and it failed.
So I downloaded docker installer from here and tried to reinstall it.

But it complains about

> Unpacking failed: 文件“C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\com.docker.service”正由另一进程使用，因此该进程无法访问此文件。
> 在 CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.d__30.MoveNext()
> — 引发异常的上一位置中堆栈跟踪的末尾 —
> 在 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> 在 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> 在 CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.d__23.MoveNext()

What should I do?

Comment: Check that the docker engine is stopped. Right click the docker icon in the taskbar (under the hidden icons) and press "Quit Docker Desktop". You can also check if docker is running in the task manager. Also try restarting the pc after stopping the engine.

Comment: Many thanks! I closed everything docker related in the task manager. Then I was able to reinstall docker again. All my data is preserved.

Comment: Please mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @kaffarell said in the comment, I closed everything Docker related in the task manager. Then I was able to reinstall docker again. All my data is preserved!

Comment: Work for me. I stop the "com.docker.service" in the task manager's service tab.